# How to write this query in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have SQL query:

`WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND C REGEXP (eee|fff|ggg)`

How can I write this query in elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but something like this **QUERY-DSL** you need for your case with `filter` and `regexp`,

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 10, 
   "query": {
        "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"A" : 1}}, 
                 { "term" : {"B" : 2}} 
              ]
           }
         },
        "regexp": {
            "C": {
                "value": "eee|fff|ggg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "A": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "B": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "regexp": {
              "C": {
                "value": "eee|fff|ggg"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```